# Comparing two shapefiles of US States using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile

I would like to use ArcMap to create an overlap of two shapefiles; i.e. Alaska vs Texas state. [link](https://www.alaska.org/assets/content/big_alaska/Alaska-Texas.jpg) (source: alaska.org/how-big-is-alaska )

Is it possible to move the Alaska shapefile next and/or to overlap Texas state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you would insert two data frames into the Layout View, set each to one of the two states, and make them the same scale.

Then you are free to place the Texas and Alaska data frames next to or overlapping one another.

Comment: Yes I did what you suggested. Seems to work fine! Thank you!